# Mixed Content Warning when viewing message in Inbox

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, images, ssl

Chrome displays a Mixed Content Warning while viewing a message in my Inbox in careers. The image of the default user is served via http instead of https.

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/xxxxx/messages/#!/inbox/messages/yyyyy'
was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/84fe84397d298b6d6b5be2ef5710e470?s=24&r=PG&d…ers.sstatic.net/careers/Img/default-user-gravatar-large.png?v=aa9a15b3b958'.
This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, this is now fixed - we're now loading the Gravatar images using HTTPS.